# MySQL Trigger, variable init fails

Tags: mysql, variables, triggers

I am trying to write a Trigger for my DB. If I want to initalise my variable Spielernr it shows me a syntax error

> #1064 - Fehler in der SQL-Syntax. Bitte die korrekte Syntax im Handbuch nachschlagen bei 'BEGIN
>       DECLARE Spielernr INT;
>       SET @Spielernr = (SELECT vereinsmitglieder.L' in Zeile 3

and I don't get the reason why. I am new in MySQL so hopefully you can give me some tips.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER addiere_ttr AFTER INSERT ON spiel

BEGIN 

DECLARE Spielernr INT;

SET Spielernr = (SELECT vereinsmitglieder.Lizenzspielernr FROM vereinsmitglieder WHERE NEW.Sieger = vereinsmitglieder.Nachname);
UPDATE ttrpunkte SET ttrpunkte.Punktezahl + 1 WHERE ttrpunkte.Lizensspielernr = Spielernr;

END //
```

Comment: Wusste ich nicht, habe die Frage abgeändert.

Comment: replace `begin` with `for each row begin`

Comment: for each row begin fixed it, thank you. Also had to write ttrpunkte.Punktezahl = ttrpunkte.Punktezahl + 1 below.